# Merging Vector Layers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, merge

I want to merge selected active layers. I tried to use `iface.activelayer` for this but of course I get an error.

This is my script:

```
V_List = iface.activeLayer[0]
    
merge = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers",
{'LAYERS':V_List,
'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('USER:100000'),
'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Additionally, I want to also merge it to a file that is changing everyday.

This is my script:

```
lay1 = r'C:/Users/CMCA/Downloads/20230318_PVDprogress.gpkg'
polygon = iface.activeLayer

merge = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers",{'LAYERS':[lay1,polygon],
                                         'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('USER:100000'),
                                         'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

Comment: Merging one layer will only add the columns `layer` and `source` to the output. You can execute the tool manually, press Ctrl+Alt+H and copy the code

Comment: In QGIS, only one layer can be active at a time. `iface.activeLayer[0]` will throw an error.

Answer (score 7):

`iface.activeLayer()` returns only the last layer clicked. It is also not subscriptable which is why, I assume, you are getting the error.

To merge all selected layers in the layer tree you can do this:

```py
view = iface.layerTreeView()
selected_nodes = view.selectedNodes()

# the selected nodes are of type QgsLayerTreeLayer, so here the corresponding QgsVectorLayer's are returned
selected_layers = [node.layer() for node in selected_nodes]

merge = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers",
            {'LAYERS':selected_layers,
             'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('USER:100000'),
             'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

To merge the selected layers with file that exists on disk, you can insert the file path into the `selected_layers` list and then merge:

```py
# the save location of the file you want to merge to (you will need to adapt this to whatever data format you are using
file_on_disk = r'C:/path/to/file'

view = iface.layerTreeView()
selected_nodes = view.selectedNodes()

selected_layers = [node.layer() for node in selected_nodes]

# insert the layer on disk into the `selected_layers` list
selected_layers.insert(0, file_on_disk)

# create an in-memory layer of the merged layers
merge = processing.runAndLoadResults("native:mergevectorlayers",
            {'LAYERS':selected_layers,
             'CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('USER:100000'),
             'OUTPUT':"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT"})
```

You can then decide what to do with the result, whether you want to replace the original file on disk, or save this result to a new location

Comment: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'view' is not defined

Comment: Did you copy the whole snippet? The code is working fine when I test it.

Comment: Hi , thank you for this , but what if I want to merge it to a layer from my directory that is changing everyday? i mean the file is being updated everytime